# Jar differs but they should not

Tags: java, jar, sha1

I have one method to create a jar.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        aha();
        aha();
        aha();
        aha();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        aha();
    }

    private static void aha() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(baos);
        jos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("sd"));
        jos.write("sdf".getBytes());
        jos.close();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha1");
        byte[] digest = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());
        for (byte b : digest) {
            System.out.print("," + b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
,-57,-44,59,113,-126,-15,71,62,-90,-120,27,36,-3,69,26,-55,63,107,-93,102
,-57,-44,59,113,-126,-15,71,62,-90,-120,27,36,-3,69,26,-55,63,107,-93,102
,-57,-44,59,113,-126,-15,71,62,-90,-120,27,36,-3,69,26,-55,63,107,-93,102
,-57,-44,59,113,-126,-15,71,62,-90,-120,27,36,-3,69,26,-55,63,107,-93,102
,-124,-26,-79,-28,-34,77,-72,83,92,53,30,-13,95,21,-92,55,70,24,-72,39
```

I need same digests but the last digest differs. How to become reproducable hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough almost invisible, if you write a `ZipEntry` to a `JarOutputStream`, the underlying `ZipOutputStream` will initialize the last modification time for you.

```
if (e.xdostime == -1) {
    // by default, do NOT use extended timestamps in extra
    // data, for now.
    e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

You would have to manually initialize the time with `setTime` get a constant result.